# How to make a sequence function for lists?

Tags: list, erlang

I'm trying to create a list in Erlang which will hold a number of integers. So if I pass in `5` it will create a list holding `[1,2,3,4,5]`. This is the code I have so far.

So I'd want to call the list something like `tower1`

```erlang
-module(towers).

-export([create_towers/1]).

create_towers( 0 ) -> [];
create_towers( N ) when N > 0 -> create_towers( N-1 ) ++ [N].
```

Comment: Like lists:seq(1, 5) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is good, the problem is the syntax

```
-module(towers).

-export([create_towers/1]).

create_towers(0) ->
    [];
create_towers(N) when N > 0 ->
    create_towers(N-1) ++ [N].
```

works fine

```
Eshell V7.1  (abort with ^G)
(emacs@Mac-mini-de-Rodrigo)1> c("/Users/rorra/erlang/towers", [{outdir, "/Users/rorra/erlang/"}]).
{ok,towers}
(emacs@Mac-mini-de-Rodrigo)2> towers:create_towers(0).
[]
(emacs@Mac-mini-de-Rodrigo)3> towers:create_towers(10).
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

---

If you want it to call the list created tower1:

```
 (emacs@Mac-mini-de-Rodrigo)2> Tower1 = towers:create_towers(5).
 [1,2,3,4,5]
```

notice that all variables starts with upperase, if you want to name the module towers1, change the file name to tower1.erl and add:

```
-module(tower1).

-export([create_towers/1]).

create_towers(0) ->
    [];
create_towers(N) when N > 0 ->
    create_towers(N-1) ++ [N].
```

and then you can call towers1:create_towers(N) like:

```
(emacs@Mac-mini-de-Rodrigo)2> MyVar = tower1:create_towers(5).
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Comment: how would I adapt the code to name the list I create to be called tower1?

Comment: Tower1 = towers:create_towers(10).

All variable on erlang starts with uppercase.

If you want to name the module towers1, so you can call towers1:create_towers(10), then change the name of the file to towers1.erl and change the -module(towers). to -module(towers1).

Comment: Thanks, that explains it!

Comment: Nice, feel free to accept my answer as a valid answer by clicking the V under the vote buttons :)

Comment: Sorry, just another quick question. If I wanted to hardcode that into the erl file. How would I do that?

Comment: You can put it on a file named tower1.erl and then compile with `erlc tower1.erl`

Comment: But if I wanted it to be in the same file, my plan is to have multiple lists created in one function

Comment: You can create all the lists you want, so imagine a erlang module is a way to organize functions and give them names, usually you enclose functionality related to a erlang module, but you can get in one single file all your program with all the needed code, its not recommended but you can totally do it. In that case, you create as many functions you want and thats it, you don't need to export these functions unless the funtions on the module will be use by external modules.

Comment: btw, I thought you were doing that code as an exercise, its not worth it to use it on a real world software, you can just write `lists:seq(0,5)` and that will build the list.